# AppleScript to convert PDF to TIFF in Preview

Tags: applescript, pdf, preview

Is there a way to use AppleScript to open a PDF and export as TIFF?

This works fine for Keynote files to TIFF:

```
tell application "Keynote"
    set doc to open "/Users/ryan/my/input/file.key"
    export doc to alias "Macintosh HD:Users:ryan:my:output:file" as slide images with properties {image format:TIFF, skipped slides: true}
end tell
```

But my attempt for Preview to turn PDFs into TIFFs isn't working

```
tell application "Preview"
    set doc to open "/Users/ryan/my/input/file.pdf"
    save doc to alias "Macintosh HD:Users:ryan:my:output:file" as TIFF with options {class:TIFF save options, embed color profile:true, save layers:true, save spot colors:true}
end tell
```

It gives the error "Expected end of line, etc. but found “to”.".

Comment: save uses 'in', not 'to', according to the Preview dictionary. FWIW, I have made a Quick Action that will split PDFs into TIFFs in the Finder, using python, if that's any help. 
https://github.com/benwiggy/PDFsuite/tree/master/Quick_Actions

Comment: Thanks Ben! I'm having a bit of trouble with this line, "pdf = Quartz.CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(Quartz.CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename(filename))" it gives the error in python3, "ValueError: depythonifying 'char', got 'str' of 1" any ideas?

Comment: works perfect in python2, thanks again!

Comment: The command for preview to save a document as a tiff is `tell application "Preview" to save document 1 as "public.tiff" in file "Drive:Path:filename.tiff"` You don't get any options however (that I'm aware of). This works in 10.12, can't say for recent releases.